# How do I access a custom variable in block.tpl.php?

Tags: blocks

I created a custom module that defines a block. In `hook_block_view()`, I have the following code.

```
$block['content'] = theme('item_list', array( 'count' => $count));
```

How can I get the value of `$count` in block.tpl.php?

Comment: Can't really give you an answer without seeing your code, or knowing what version of Drupal you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your block with hook_block_info(). Now you need to use hook_block_view() to add your variables to the content array which can be called in your template file.

Answer (score 0):

The [block.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.tpl.php/7.x) template file receives in `$content` what you put in `$block['content']` in `hook_block_view()`.

Since you are putting the output of a theme function in `$block['content']`, you would need to filter out the HTML tags from `$content`, to get the value of `$count`.

Alternatively, you can use the following code in `hook_block_view()`.

```php
$block['content'] = $count;
```

In that way, if other modules don't alter the content of your block, you get the value of `$count` straight in `$content`, inside block.tpl.php.